# How to run consecutive commands in bash script? (Synclient)

Tags: scripts, touchpad, synaptics

I have an executable document about stops and starts touchpad, that includes;

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse;
```

I added ";" between commands so it can run consecutively. Then, I want to add some Synclient commands there for example;

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse;
sudo synclient AccelFactor=0.1;
```

But it only runs the modprobe command, it does not run synclient command.
Why it can be? And how can I make it run that command, should I add some wait timer I don't know it makes sense?

Comment: Don't put sudo in scripts. Run the script itself using sudo. Mind that if those commands do not show an error that means those commands DID execute. Maybe the result it not as expected?

Comment: I don't use synclient but I tested the script with echo "hello" as the second line and it was executed fine so perhaps an issue specifically with synclient? Is this a command which stays open and monitors the trackpad continuously? What happens if you remove the last ; or replace it with & ?

Comment: How do you know the command does not run? Perhaps it runs, but not successfully?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am newbie so didn't know that I shouldn't put sudo commands in script, and now I do. Thank you!
And, I do know the command does not run because when I type "synclient" I can see AccelFactor haven't changed. But I know the other two worked, because for a second my touchpad stops working, then it comes back to normal.